# How would i create a loop in c++ that updates in realtime overwriting the previous entry

Tags: c++

For example:

```
float count1 = 0;
float count2 = 0;

for(int i = 0; i<1000000; i++) {
    printf("Calculation plus 1: %f", count1);
    printf("Calculation plus 2: %f", count2);
    count1++;
    count2 += 2;
}
```

How would i get these counters running live on the terminal output, updating in real time.
WITHOUT using a new line.
OVERWRITING the previous output.
looking something similar to this: http://bkm.billking.io/projects/pi/

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388628/c-change-output-from-cout

Comment: Does `++` even work on `float`s? That seems a little wonky...

Comment: It is wonky as the float will eventually saturate at some point.

Answer (score 3):

Neither C nor C++ provide a 'works everywhere' solution.

---

I have used '\r' to place the cursor on top of the 1st char in a line.
But this seems insufficient for your needs.

(By the way, I think you mean to have a '\n' at the end of each of your current printf.)

Example of use of carriage-return for overwrite:

```
std::cout << "\r " << showProgressW(" ") << std::flush;
```

The 'showProgressW()' generates a string including "% complete" and a "byte count" and other progress info during an operation that can take multiple 10's of seconds. During this operation, no other thread can write to the std::cout (which has thread unsafe issues).

---

For text output (when the user device supports this), I find
ANSI escape sequences straight forward.    Example:

```
inline void gotoxy (int col = 1, int row = 1) { printf ("\e[%d;%dH", row, col );   };
inline void gotoxy (char *col, char *row)     { printf ("\e[%s;%sH", row,  col);   };
```

With these functions, you can place the cursor back on top of the first char of any output field, then output the new value.  (I usually use std::cout instead of printf.)  There are quite a few other escape sequences, and combinations, that might be useful in simple efforts i.e.   cursor up (down, left, right) n lines

---

For text output where a minimal 'windowing' style might be helpful, I use curses, which is somewhat more involved.

---

I think the next choices involve gui i/o.